# Using a servo motor for precice angles doesnt work (Python, Raspberry PI without Arduino)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, servo

Im working on a little robot and im trying to implement a second motor, that allows to turn the wheel by certain degrees. I used a servo motor MG995 Tower Pro

However i cant turn it through certain degrees. It turns everytime for the same time as my time.sleep command.

Here is the code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep
servo_pin = 18

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(servo_pin, 50)

pwm= GPIO.PWM(servo_pin, 50)
pwm.start(0)

def move_servo(angle):
     duty = angle / 18 + 3
     GPIO.output(servo_pin, True)
     pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(duty)
     sleep(1)
     GPIO.output(servo_pin, False)
     pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(duty)
move_servo(35)
pwm.stop()
GPIO.cleanup()
```

This is the Servo in question:
https://www.towerpro.com.tw/product/mg995/

The biggest problem is, i think it doesnt hold the same angle when using the same command multiple times. Its running on a Rasperry Pi. maybe there are better options for specific angle movement?

Sincerely Pascal

Tried changing the time.sleep() command, manually chaning duty cycle so it turns exactly 90 degrees. But i cant get so precise, that it works

Comment: If you want precise turn angles you should consider using a stepper motor rather than a servo.  The stepper will make an exact angle change for each step which is repeatable in both the forward and reverse directions.  I don't believe it is possible to get close tolerance repeatability on the angle of rotation with a servo.

Comment: @itprorh66 i heard about absolute encoders with dc motors, but the only stuff i find is way too expensive.

Comment: Im a bit scarred to find the zero point on the stepper if you disconnect the controller mid turning